# $dy/dx = y \sin x-2\sin x$, $y(0) = 0$ -- Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\sin x-2\sin x, \quad y(0) = 0.$$

Initial Value Problem

Hint says: Find an integrating factor

Comment: Welcome to this Math Stack Exchange. Notice that your "question" is kind of a rude implication that the community is just expected to compute your answer, like a robot. It's more helpful if you actually ask a question, and give as much information as you can about why you are stuck. For example, do you not know what an "integrating factor " is?

Comment: No I do not. What is an integrating factor?

Comment: I still cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

When we have a linear differential equation $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$ of order 1 then $\mu (x)=e^{\int P(x) dx}$will be an integrating factor. In your case, it is $\mu(x)=e^{\cos(x)}$. Now multiply it both sides of the equation and you see $$d(e^{\cos(x)}y)=-2\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}$$ The rest is easy.

Comment: What do I do next?

Comment: @Ryan: Did you get the right answer? :-)

Comment: I think with your help, Ryan got the right answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

If a differential equation has the form

$$ y'(x)+p(x)y(x)=q(x)\,, \quad (1), $$ then the integrating factor is given by

$$ m(x)= {\rm e}^{\int p(x) dx}\,. $$

You need to write your ode in the form of $(1)$ and then find the integrating factor. Then just multiply the original equation by the interating factor and integrate

$$ (m(x)y)'= q(x) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(e^{\cos(x)}y)=-2\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow e^{\cos(x)}y(x)=2\int e^{\cos(x)}(-\sin(x))dx + C = 2e^{\cos(x)} +C $$

$$ y(x)= 2 + C \,{\rm e}^{-\cos(x)} \,.$$

To find $C$, you need to use the initial condition $y(0)=0$,

$$ y(0) = 0 = 2 + C{\rm e}^{-\cos(0)} \Rightarrow C = -2 {\rm e}$$

Substituting the value of $C$ in the solution gives

$$ y(x)= 2 - 2  \,{\rm e}^{1-\cos(x)} \,.$$

Comment: So I got the integral, but how would I integrate: e^(coax)y(x)?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest type of this ODE is that separable rather than linear. So it is not necessary to treat it as a linear ODE to solve.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y\sin x-2\sin x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(y-2)\sin x$

$\dfrac{dy}{y-2}=\sin x~dx$

$\int\dfrac{dy}{y-2}=\int\sin x~dx$

$\ln(y-2)=-\cos x+c$

$y-2=Ce^{-\cos x}$

$y=Ce^{-\cos x}+2$

$y(0)=0$ :

$Ce^{-1}+2=0$

$C=-2e$

$\therefore y=-2ee^{-\cos x}+2=2-2e^{1-\cos x}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write it as $\frac{y'}{y-2}=\sin(x)$ and integrate.

Comment: The answer above is correct.  However, if the person asking the question insists you use the hint, then you write the ODE as $