# Initial Value Problem: $\frac{dy}{dx} = y\sin x - 2\sin x,\quad y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$dy/dx = y \sin x-2\sin x$, $y(0) = 0$ — Initial Value Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207401/dy-dx-y-sin-x-2-sin-x-y0-0-initial-value-problem)

> $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\sin x - 2\sin x,\quad y(0) = 0$$

So, I get

$$\frac{1}{y-2} dy = \sin x dx.$$

Then, I integrated and got

$$\ln(y-2) =-\cos x + C.$$

Then, I did $e$^ both sides, but I end up with $\ln(-2)$ which is an error.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't get the answer from the responses in my previous question. I have indicated above where I am stuck.

Comment: Here is the [solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207401/dy-dx-y-sin-x-2-sin-x-y0-0-initial-value-problem/207412#207412).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, except that, as differentiating $ln(-x)$ one also gets $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{-x}=\frac1x$, so it can be $ln(2-y)$ as well.

That's how is meant $\displaystyle\int\frac1xdx=ln|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y\sin x-2\sin x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(y-2)\sin x$

$\dfrac{dy}{y-2}=\sin x~dx$

$\int\dfrac{dy}{y-2}=\int\sin x~dx$

$\ln(y-2)=-\cos x+c$

$y-2=Ce^{-\cos x}$

$y=Ce^{-\cos x}+2$

$y(0)=0$ :

$Ce^{-1}+2=0$

$C=-2e$

$\therefore y=-2ee^{-\cos x}+2=2-2e^{1-\cos x}$

Comment: Yes, but.. if $c\in\mathbb R$ then $C=e^c>0$, and you got $C=-2e<0$..

Comment: You don't need to worry. $e^c$ can be $<0$ , the only thing is that $c$ should be a complex number. Moreover, I consider $y=Ce^{-\cos x}+2$ for substitute $y(0)=0$ rather than consider $\ln(y-2)=-\cos x+c$ .