# Please help to solve this ODE with function coefficients

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Is it possible to solve this ODE for $y$?  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions) this falls in the category of a first order, linear, inhomogeneous ODE with function coefficients.  But is there a more tractable general solution than the one offered on that page?

The ODE is:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}f(t)+y \:g(t)=h(t)$$

where the LHS is just the product rule for $\frac{d}{dt}\left(y(t)f(t)\right)$, and so:

$$g(t)=\frac{df}{dt}$$

and it is also known that $$h(t)=\frac{t\:q(t)}{f(t)}$$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207401/dy-dx-y-sin-x-2-sin-x-y0-0-initial-value-problem/207412#207412).

Comment: Were you referring to this write-up? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation

Comment: @ben what, if anything, is known about $q(t)$ you write in the numerator of the quotient formula for $h(t)$?

Comment: @Amzoti No, but that is helpful.  I had not seen that one.  I will edit the question to put in the wikipedia link I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The integrating factor method is often successful in finding explicit closed-form solutions of standard problems. But, for certain problems other methods are known. Pfaff's Theorem states that there exists an integrating factor $I$ (not necessarily the standard one as discussed in the elementary DEqns course) which makes a first order ODE exact. However, finding $I$ is as difficult as finding the solution to the DEqn of interest. So, generically speaking one hopes for a clever substitution to appear since deriving the substitution is as hard as the problem itself. That said, I think this problem is more about integration than some other technique.

For your problem, if I assume $q=g$ (which may be mere wishful thinking on my part) then your problem becomes:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} [ yf ] = \frac{t}{f}\frac{df}{dt} $$
But, we can write this as,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} [ yf ] = t\frac{d}{dt} \ln(f) $$
Well, this is a lovely formula, I can integrate it and with the technique of integration by parts derive a nice solution up to an integral for the given problem,
$$ yf =  t\ln(f)-\int \ln(f) dt $$
hence,
$$ y =  \frac{1}{f} \biggl( t\ln(f)-\int \ln(f) dt +C \biggr). $$

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful, but unfortunately it is wishful thinking to equate g(t) to q(t).

Answer (score 0):

the integrating factor method is to be applied

Comment: It would be advisable to expand your answer to include a (short) account of the "integrating factor method" and how it applies to this situation.